# Как реализовать наезд одного блока на второй при прокрутке?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день!
Как реализовать следующий эффект - у меня есть 2 блока. 1й при загрузке сайта открывается на всю высоту и ширину экрана. Второй при прокрутке как бы наезжает на него.
[Вот пример](http://theme-quantist.tumblr.com/)

Как сделать точно также, только без эффекта параллакса на бекграунде?
Просто эффект наезда нижнего блока на верхний.

Comment: а почему бы не одолжить идею реализации с сайта, который вы приводите в пример? открывайте отладчик и смотрите стили, которые там прописаны

Comment: @lexxl, я пробовала, но ничего путевого не вышло((

Comment: Make_dev  просто тыкнете там на странице `ПКМ` и сохраните на `Рабочий стол` и готовое сохранится со всеми скриптами но без изображений или с ними , я так делал и готовое получилось - только поправить надо чуток

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем, посидев-подумав, решила свою проблему самостоятельно.
Вот рабочий пример.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
.banner-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.media-wrapper {
  position: static;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.media-wrapper::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  height: 500px;
  /*В рабочем проекте поставить высоту 100%*/
  background-color: #f3f2f7;
}
.content {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
.clearfix:after,
.clearfix:before {
  content: " ";
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section class="banner-wrapper">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident nostrum incidunt qui velit, quo iusto repellat quia minus praesentium vitae, obcaecati quam sapiente nesciunt fuga doloremque itaque, fugiat facere! Nihil.

  </section>
  <section class="media-wrapper clearfix">
    <div class="content">
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, ullam tempore quidem. Necessitatibus laudantium cum tempora quaerat distinctio odio accusamus, delectus placeat quibusdam, aut eos ratione ex rem nulla, nisi!</div>
      <div>Velit quo porro, nesciunt soluta non obcaecati quos nisi, tenetur ut deleniti itaque voluptas reprehenderit eos suscipit? Error iusto quidem, nam nesciunt aspernatur ex doloribus cumque illum velit, quas, qui?</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, ullam tempore quidem. Necessitatibus laudantium cum tempora quaerat distinctio odio accusamus, delectus placeat quibusdam, aut eos ratione ex rem nulla, nisi!</div>
      <div>Velit quo porro, nesciunt soluta non obcaecati quos nisi, tenetur ut deleniti itaque voluptas reprehenderit eos suscipit? Error iusto quidem, nam nesciunt aspernatur ex doloribus cumque illum velit, quas, qui?</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, ullam tempore quidem. Necessitatibus laudantium cum tempora quaerat distinctio odio accusamus, delectus placeat quibusdam, aut eos ratione ex rem nulla, nisi!</div>
      <div>Velit quo porro, nesciunt soluta non obcaecati quos nisi, tenetur ut deleniti itaque voluptas reprehenderit eos suscipit? Error iusto quidem, nam nesciunt aspernatur ex doloribus cumque illum velit, quas, qui?</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, ullam tempore quidem. Necessitatibus laudantium cum tempora quaerat distinctio odio accusamus, delectus placeat quibusdam, aut eos ratione ex rem nulla, nisi!</div>
      <div>Velit quo porro, nesciunt soluta non obcaecati quos nisi, tenetur ut deleniti itaque voluptas reprehenderit eos suscipit? Error iusto quidem, nam nesciunt aspernatur ex doloribus cumque illum velit, quas, qui?</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, ullam tempore quidem. Necessitatibus laudantium cum tempora quaerat distinctio odio accusamus, delectus placeat quibusdam, aut eos ratione ex rem nulla, nisi!</div>
      <div>Velit quo porro, nesciunt soluta non obcaecati quos nisi, tenetur ut deleniti itaque voluptas reprehenderit eos suscipit? Error iusto quidem, nam nesciunt aspernatur ex doloribus cumque illum velit, quas, qui?</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, ullam tempore quidem. Necessitatibus laudantium cum tempora quaerat distinctio odio accusamus, delectus placeat quibusdam, aut eos ratione ex rem nulla, nisi!</div>
      <div>Velit quo porro, nesciunt soluta non obcaecati quos nisi, tenetur ut deleniti itaque voluptas reprehenderit eos suscipit? Error iusto quidem, nam nesciunt aspernatur ex doloribus cumque illum velit, quas, qui?</div>
      <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rerum, ullam tempore quidem. Necessitatibus laudantium cum tempora quaerat distinctio odio accusamus, delectus placeat quibusdam, aut eos ratione ex rem nulla, nisi!</div>
      <div>Velit quo porro, nesciunt soluta non obcaecati quos nisi, tenetur ut deleniti itaque voluptas reprehenderit eos suscipit? Error iusto quidem, nam nesciunt aspernatur ex doloribus cumque illum velit, quas, qui?</div>
      <div>Atque in, exercitationem neque voluptates? Dolorem pariatur a, quam consequatur ab voluptatibus, esse consectetur perferendis natus, quas ratione, provident dolorum? Quasi inventore est labore quis commodi, obcaecati repellendus a ullam.</div>
      <div>Eveniet sapiente necessitatibus fugiat quidem ducimus voluptas quae neque tenetur laudantium vero ullam pariatur enim omnis amet maxime, id, consectetur aut quos, illo culpa numquam porro nostrum. Fuga, vero? Voluptatum.</div>
      <div>Eveniet quibusdam quam voluptas id beatae aspernatur vel vitae, odit distinctio quasi veniam eum commodi nesciunt odio consequuntur. Porro laborum accusamus maiores distinctio, cumque in perferendis voluptas sed, recusandae labore.</div>
      <div>Sequi non suscipit laborum deserunt ducimus voluptatum excepturi voluptas velit quam in, repellendus aliquam nisi. Sequi sint itaque repudiandae dolor, perspiciatis illo vel commodi libero odio quos enim molestiae dicta?</div>
      <div>Mollitia necessitatibus nostrum voluptatem fugiat excepturi recusandae illo! Aliquid, iste delectus minus expedita nostrum eius ex assumenda aliquam reprehenderit placeat omnis repellat corporis cupiditate quae libero. Nulla laboriosam excepturi,
        nemo?</div>
      <div>Sequi inventore suscipit libero tenetur facilis qui, animi provident earum et. Eum fuga iure iusto? Totam, quos. Error pariatur, nam magnam beatae, nihil adipisci autem aliquam, maxime obcaecati suscipit eligendi!</div>
      <div>Maxime veniam quibusdam explicabo dolore sint commodi ducimus at modi neque ea expedita error alias voluptatibus cum blanditiis dolor, reiciendis quidem quaerat consequuntur saepe perferendis est nihil. Natus, quidem, soluta.</div>
<div>Maxime veniam quibusdam explicabo dolore sint commodi ducimus at modi neque ea expedita error alias voluptatibus cum blanditiis dolor, reiciendis quidem quaerat consequuntur saepe perferendis est nihil. Natus, quidem, soluta.</div>
<div>Maxime veniam quibusdam explicabo dolore sint commodi ducimus at modi neque ea expedita error alias voluptatibus cum blanditiis dolor, reiciendis quidem quaerat consequuntur saepe perferendis est nihil. Natus, quidem, soluta.</div>
<div>Maxime veniam quibusdam explicabo dolore sint commodi ducimus at modi neque ea expedita error alias voluptatibus cum blanditiis dolor, reiciendis quidem quaerat consequuntur saepe perferendis est nihil. Natus, quidem, soluta.</div>
<div>Maxime veniam quibusdam explicabo dolore sint commodi ducimus at modi neque ea expedita error alias voluptatibus cum blanditiis dolor, reiciendis quidem quaerat consequuntur saepe perferendis est nihil. Natus, quidem, soluta.</div>

    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

Когда то делал такое в качестве эксперимента, но ни в одном реальном проекте не применял. Не забудьте про reset.css.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  var posTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
  
  document.body.style.backgroundPosition =  'center -' + posTop/5 + 'px';
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1920/1200/);
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center 0vw;
}

.header-bar {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 3em;
}
.menu-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 7em;
}
.offer-bar {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50vh;
}
.main-bar {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header-bar">
</div>
<div class="menu-bar">
</div>
<div class="offer-bar">
</div>
<div class="main-bar">
</div>
<div calss="footer-bar">
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо за код, но это немного не тот эффект, что мне нужен. Мне нужно, чтобы блок, на который наезжает нижний элемент, не прокручивался.

Comment: я могу вам готовый код отдать , если хотите

Comment: да? тогда все упрощается. посмотрите второй ответ. так?

Comment: я Make_dev писал

Comment: удивительно, я тоже )

Comment: Ребятки, вот какой эффект мне надо. Как в футере этого сайта - только наоборот, чтобы блок наезжал на верхний, а не съезжал http://wptemplates.pehaa.com/yaga/ Или вот эффект  в хедере http://wpspade.com/vong/ . И вот еще http://defatch-demo.com/themes/william/#0

Comment: @Make_dev все еще не понятно, что вы хотите.. второй мой ответ не подходит?

Comment: @AndreyFedorov, хочу эффект, как в футере этого сайта http://wptemplates.pehaa.com/yaga/ :) Видите, как внизу блок с картой съезжает с футера? Вот мне надо зеркальный эффект:) чтобы нижний блок так наезжал на верхний.  2 ваш ответ тоже немножко не такой, как нужно

Comment: Make_dev пишите на почту мне , я вам дам готовый код

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1920/1200');
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
div {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin-top: 70vh;
  padding: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur, dicta aut a at sunt quasi aspernatur. Ullam porro, consequatur est quo voluptatum atque. Delectus, dicta, saepe? Delectus sapiente officiis soluta maiores voluptatum voluptates culpa. Libero consectetur aliquid temporibus, dignissimos
</div>
```